# What does the squirt do that stays in Bastion?

Tags: bastion

So I started playing Bastion and so far have the first 3 cores, but there's something that's bugging me.

After getting the first core and returning back to the Bastion (and getting the `Squirt Lure`), a squirt stays with you at the Bastion and seems to do... nothing.

[image: the squirt]

When it initially appeared, it seemed to like me when I interacted with it (it had the floating hearts around it).  But the next time I did, the hearts does not appear any more and it gives an angry look.  To be precise, I talked to it and rolled away not really paying attention.  Then Rucks (the "Stranger") mentioned something along the lines of, "that's not how you treat it."  Now, every time I try to interact with it, it gives the angry look and nothing else happens.  Eventually I cannot interact with it any more until I leave and return back to the Bastion but it still gives me the angry look.

Did I do something wrong to hurt it's feelings?  (I guess I damaged it when I rolled away)  What sort of actions do/can I do to make it like me again?  Or am I just worrying about nothing and it's just the way it behaves until I progress further into the game?

So far, everything else seems to have a purpose except for that squirt.  Does it even do anything else or is it just there for show?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pets do 3 things:

- If you click them enough, it will cause Rucks to say something. It will also cause them to do something.
- You can get an achievement for getting all 4 pets.
- Plot Spoiler:

> Later on in the plot, The Bastion will be attacked. Any pets that you have acquired will  help defend against the attack. You can fight the attack off yourself if you have no pets, but the pets make it easier. You may lose a few of your pets in the attack, but they won't do anything after the attack aside from hang out, so don't worry if you lose a few of them. As for Squirt being angry, you're fine. I did the same thing and he still participated in the attack.

Comment: I'm a little sad now, I've just reached that part of the game and lost the fourth one (the bird thing).

Comment: I am weeping for them :(

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how long it takes, but every time you return to the Bastion click on the squirt. He ... it(?) will spin around for every level you have completed. After enough time (again, I don't know the number) he will grow to a large squirt. This large squirt will be of more help later in the game.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you did anything wrong. From what I can tell, it doesn't really do much - it is just decoration, really. You'll get a few other creatures later in the game that are the same, there just for show.

Comment: Yeah, I got to the point where I got another creature thing (the Pyth) that seems to be doing nothing too (looks like they're "trophies").  The part that I don't understand is why the squirt "liked" me at first but now "hates" me.  I would have been ok if the way it acted didn't change and there was no comment from Rucks but there was so it feels like there's a bit more to it than that.

Comment: They're mostly trophies, but they do have [another purpose](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28244/what-does-the-squirt-do-that-stays-in-bastion/28285#28285).